# Python: efficient way to store objects

Tags: python, list, memory

I have to store 300+ Objects (users) in memory and get those users according to their ID.
What is the most efficient way to do this?

Currently i'm storing the objects in a list, to get a user from the list i use this code:

```
[u for u in users if u.id == id]
```

This doesn't seem to be very efficient as i have to iterate over the whole list in the worst case.

Comment: Create a dict one time and access direclty using key

Comment: Are these ids in sequential numeric form. If yes than you can directly get them by their index, else dictionary would be great.

Comment: Nope, users are not ordered. I think using a dict would be best. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a dict.

`users = {}`

add the values of each user as follows.

`users[user_id] = "user_value"`

You may just extract the particular record via the user id as

`users[user_id]`

You may store this either in mongo or store it using pickle.

Answer (score 2):

Or use generators

instead of using a list comprehension dict use a tuple

`(u for u in users if u.id == id)`

**EDIT**

If the ids are unique my solution has nothing to do, the dict one is better, but it the issue is performance related the generator way has a good performance peak, like my performance test will show :

```
import timeit

setup = """
from random import randint

class User:
    id = randint(0,10000)

users = [User() for _ in range(0,100)]

def generator_sample(users):
    final = (u for u in users if u.id == 100)

def list_sample(users):
    final = [u for u in users if u.id == 100]
"""

print timeit.timeit('generator_sample(users)', setup=setup)  # 0.413088083267
print timeit.timeit('list_sample(users)', setup=setup) # 4.37370610237
```